# Prevent duplicated entries for two foreign keys in laravel factory using faker

Tags: php, laravel, faker

I am going to implement a database like this:

Tables :

- Items : id(pk),code unique()
- Stores : id(pk), name,address
- Inventories : id(pk), item_id(fk), store_id(fk), count

ex:
I have item with unique code "k1" and i have 3 stores for example : s1,s2,s3,now

i should have in inventory like this

- k1,s1,500   "k1 item exists in store 1(s1) with count of 500" (ok for this case)
- k1,s2,200   "k2 item exists in store 2(s2) with count of 200" (ok for this case)
- k1,s3 300   "k3 item exists in store 3(s3) with count of 300" (ok for this case)

I want k1 and s1 (foreign keys) to make a new composite key in inventory table to

avoid duplicated rows like

k1,s1,250 or k1,s2,100, or k1,s3,45

in another word i don't want foreign keys for item and store to be duplicated more than 1 row in the pivot table
"item_id and store_id make a unique row in inventory table"

I am already implemented that, my problem now is:

Using laravel and using Factory with faker, i need your help to do that which is to prevents duplicated entries with foreign keys

this is my factories code :

```
$factory->define(Item::class, function (Faker $faker) {
return [
    'code' => $faker->unique()->name,
    'cat_id' => Cat::all()->random()->id
];
});
$factory->define(Store::class, function (Faker $faker) {
return [
    'name' => $faker->unique()->name,
    'location' => $faker->address()

];
});


$factory->define(Inventory::class, function (Faker $faker) {
return [
    // now here i want to generate faked data with no duplicated rows using fks
    'item_id' => Item::all()->id,
    'store_id' => Store::all()->id

];
});
```

Comment: Have you tried something like this: 
`'item_id' => function () {
            return factory(App\Item::class)->create()->id;
        }` and the same for store..

Comment: No, I am going to try it

Comment: But this approach will prevent duplication in entries?

Comment: id returned will always be unique (assuming it is the unique incrementing primary key on both tables). Therefore, it is impossible to get a duplicate combination.

Comment: Yes, i understood that, thank you my friend

Answer (score 0):

How about changing your approach a little and doing some thing like below ( Beware I haven't tested the code as giving you my 2 pence on it )

```
$factory->define(Inventory::class, function (Faker $faker) {
   return [
     'item_id' => function() {
        return factory(Item::class)->create()->id;
      },
     'store_id' => function() {
        return factory(Store::class)->create()->id;
      },
  ];
```

});

Comment: Hi ,
How this approach preventing from duplicated in entries?
i am going to test it

Comment: Didnt see ur comment when i was writing the solution before headed for lunch break @user3532758.

Comment: Please do add some explanation to your code to enable one to understand what the code does and prevent copy-pasting what may not work